# Not able to save image at desired location/folder using AutoIT with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, download, autoit, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to download an image from a website using AutoIT(to control OS Pop up Window) and Selenium Webdriver(to open the website from where i am trying to download the pic).
I am getting the OS Pop Up window and by using AutoIT i am able to send the new location for saving the file **i.e** ,

```
C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\Resume\Pic.jpg
```

But once the script clicks on the save button the pic get downloaded but with a different name and at a different/default location.

AutoIT Script which i am using is written below-

```
WinWait("Save As");
WinActive("Save As");
Sleep(1000);
ControlSetText("Save As","","[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]","C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\Resume\Pic.jpg");
Sleep(1000);
ControlClick("Save As","","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]");
Sleep(1000);
```

Java code for Webdriver-

```
  import java.awt.AWTException;
  import java.awt.Robot;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

 public class Practice {

 public void pic() throws AWTException, IOException, InterruptedException{

     WebDriver driver;
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver.exe");
     driver = new ChromeDriver();
     try{
      driver.navigate().to("https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKZOx.jpg?s=128&g=1");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
       action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/img"))).perform();
        action.contextClick().perform();
      Robot robo = new Robot();
        robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
      robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    // Here i am getting the os window but don't know how to send the desired location
        String command ="C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\Resume\\Pic.exe";
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        driver.close();
    }//catch
     finally{
         Thread.sleep(6000);
         System.out.println("command");
         driver.quit();
         System.exit(0);
     }
  }//method
```

[image: ScreenShot during exxecution of Program]

As you can see it is succsesfully sending the new address to the OS Window Pop (inside red circle)  but after clicking on Save button the image is getting downloaded at different location **`C:\Users\Casper\Downloads (my default download folder)`** with a different name -rKZOx

Comment: What happens if you do it manually? The same? If it doesn't work at all, you could move the file afterwards with FileMove :-)

Comment: @Xenobiologist No if i try doing it manually its saving the image to the desired location i.e, C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\Resume with the name Pic

Comment: try to set download.dir preference to dwnload it to desired directory and then perform your tasks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here.  Is the java induced popup necessary here?  Why not just capture the pic url, and use InetGet() in AutoIt?

Comment: @SmOke_N I tried it and it worked for me but for the file upload i am again facing the same issue. Thats why i am looking for a help? Am i doing or missing something in my script

Comment: @Shantanu, the word "upload" anywhere in your description would have saved you and I both some time ;).  I gave a complete solution below, it should work with both upload/download, and ensure your file is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i got the answer. Since i was not waiting for the window to open properly i was not able to download the file at my desired location. I just put a Thread wait for 2 seconds and now its working fine and saving the image at the desired location. Changed code is-

Rest of the code remain same the below code is changed -

```
  Thread.wait(2000);
   String command ="C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\Resume\\Pic.exe";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

And now i am able to save image at e drive with the name of the file as pic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
Global $goExplorer = _myExplorerSelectUpload("C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\Resume", "Pic.exe", "Save As")
If @error Then Exit 101

ControlClick(HWnd($goExplorer.hwnd),"","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")

Func _myExplorerSelectUpload($szDirectory, $szFileName, $vWndOrTitle, $sText = "")

    Local $oExplorer = _explorerWinFindObj($vWndOrTitle, $sText)
    If @error Then Return SetError(@error, @extended, 0)

    $oExplorer.Navigate($szDirectory)
    If @error Then Return SetError(3, 0, 0)
    ; might try a sleep here if it's rendering too fast

    $oExplorer.document.SelectItem( _
        $oExplorer.document.Folder.ParseName($szFileName), 1 + 4 + 8 + 16)
    If @error Then Return SetError(5, 0, 0)

    ; return the object you're working with
    Return $oExplorer
EndFunc

Func _explorerWinFindObj($vWndOrTitle, $sText = "")

    Local $oShell = ObjCreate("Shell.Application")
    If Not IsObj($oShell) Then
        Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    EndIf

    Local $oWins = $oShell.windows
    Local $hWnd, $vDummy

    For $oWin In $oWins

        ; browser confirmation - start
        $vDummy = $oWin.type
        If Not @error Then ContinueLoop ; if not/browser

        $vDummy = $oWin.document.title
        If Not @error Then ContinueLoop
        ; browser confirmation - end

        ; bypassed IE windows, now to find window
        $hWnd = HWnd($oWin.hwnd)
        If IsHWnd($vWndOrTitle) Then
            ; hwnd was passed, does it equal hwnd of object
            If $hWnd = $vWndOrTitle Then Return $oWin
        Else
            ; match titles (exact match)
            If WinGetTitle($hWnd) = $vWndOrTitle Then
                ; match text, only in string text match
                If $sText And Not _
                    StringInStr(WinGetText($hWnd), $sText) Then
                    ContinueLoop
                EndIf
                Return $oWin
                ; hwnd to hwnd
            ElseIf WinGetHandle($vWndOrTitle, $sText) = $hWnd Then
                Return $oWin
            EndIf
        EndIf
    Next

    Return SetError(2, 0, 0)
EndFunc
```